# Why can't i get onto the apple website?

Tags: google-chrome, itunes, website, download

i've tried 3 different browsers, i've tried clearing the cache, and i've tried turning allm hardware off and on again

i can get onto heaps of other websites, i can even get onto apple's on line computer catalog, just not iTunes or any of the other pages of the site, My friend i was talking to on-line said he could get onto the iTunes page, but i can't, i can't work out what's going on.

when i try in IE of firefox i can't get past the previous page, when i try in googele chrome it goes blank and gets no further.

[i have a whole lot of half-installed apple software on my PC, like iTunes and stuff (i replaced the drive windows was on, but a lot of the software was installed on another drive), but i don't know how that could stop me getting to the website.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not alone. I've been having problems bringing up pages on the Apple web site for the last few days. Today though it (finally) seems to be working fine. So perhaps ... try it again?

If all other sites are working for you and only the Apple site is having problems it is probably something Apple knows about, is working on, but just doesn't want to talk about to avoid bad PR. IMO.

If you think it may be a problem with a DNS server you can also try using an alternate DNS server such as OpenDNS or Google.

Answer (score 0):

check the hosts file here: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc and make sure it doesn't contain any entries with regards to apple.

Comment: no, none, only had a brief look but that has recently been wiped and re-installed so i didn't think there'd be much, how would that stop their website working for me anyway though

Comment: @Bec: If there were entries for the Apple web site and they were incorrect ... the IP addresses were no longer valid ... then that would prevent you from accessing the site. Bit of a long shot, but not out of the question. More likely is a problem with a DNS server. I've had changes for a URL not get properly flushed out to the DNS server I was using which prevented me from accessing that site using the URL. That's a big reason why I started using OpenDNS ...

Comment: it upgraded to just being obscenely slow today, does that rule out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I could be a network issue.

Ensure you can ping their website. In a console (Winkey+R) run:

```
cmd /K "ping www.apple.com"
```

If you don't see something like "Reply from 96.16.93.15: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=57", then it's definitely a network issue. In this case, you'll need to contact your network administrator or ISP to get help resolving the issue. In the meantime, try rebooting and/or waiting a while.